# Datetimepicker two options select date from dropdown or manualy ovewrite

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm making a datetimepicker which can save the date by selecting a "pay" date from  a dropdown menu and it also should be enable to save the date by manualy clicking a date on the calandar and after that it will be saved in a db. The manual option always has to override the dates from the dropdown.

But here is the problem, I have no idea how to make the Onclick function if this is even possible in a datetimepicker. So far the dropdown options always overwrite the manualy selected date which i dont want it to do.

```
 dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
 MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());
```

Anyone has a good idea?

(dropdown code:)

The dropdown code is in dutch sorry, In the dropdown menu u have 4 options (like +14 days +7 days) resdatum means how many days it has to go up. Factuur datum means the start date and betaaldatum basicly is the start date + the amount of days from resdatum.

```
Locatie_reservering lr = new Locatie_reservering();
            string ResDatum = lr.getFirstDate(reservering.getID());
            DateTime FactuurDatum = betalingsConditie.BerekenFactuurdatum(cbBetalingsConditie.SelectedValue.ToString(), ResDatum);
            DateTime BetaalDatum = betalingsConditie.BerekenBetaaldatum(cbBetalingsConditie.SelectedValue.ToString(), FactuurDatum, ResDatum);
            dateTimePicker1.Value = BetaalDatum;
```

Comment: Please specify the technology (winforms, wpf, ...)

Comment: Are you creating your own datetimepicker component?

Answer (score 1):

You can use MouseUp event:

```
    private void dateTimePicker1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        MessageBox.Show(dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Already tried that and the dropdown dates will overwrite the manualy selected date

Comment: Then I don't understand your problem. You have to ask right question. For example what do you mean by *override the dates from the dropdown* or what is the *betalingsConditie.BerekenBetaaldatum*

Comment: @VanoMaisuradze i think `betalingsConditie` is a class object and `BerekenBetaaldatum` is a method. It's dutch :)

Comment: @VanoMaisuradze eddited the question i hope this will clear it out ;p

Answer (score 0):

Try using the datetimepicker's ValueChanged event. This will be fired whenever the datetime is changed.

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  textBox1.Text = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
}
```